# vb.net strict use of textbox autocomplete source

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there any way to strictly use only text from my autocompletesource? Including the usage of upper/lower case characters. With my current code, when I type a small letter at first, then suggestion will popup. But when going to another tabindex, it will leave the textbox without completing the textbox suggested inputs. Any ideas or alternatives?

```
Try
     Dim dt As New DataTable
     Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select check_group FROM tblchecklist", conn)
         conn.Open()
         dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
     End Using
     Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
     For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
         col.Add(row("check_group").ToString)
     Next
     txt_group.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
     txt_group.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
     txt_group.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append

 Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
 End Try
```

Comment: There's nothing automatic. Handle the `Leave` event and clean up the text yourself if desired. Otherwise, use a `ComboBox` instead of a `Textbox`, which also supports autocomplete and can use the drop-down items as the source.